# Fazendo "como chegar" com destino pré-definido

Tags: google-maps

Preciso de uma página onde carregue o **iframe** do Google Maps e que o usuário possa colocar o endereço onde mora, e quando ele clica em *como chegar* ele traça a rota de um local que eu vou pré-definir. Que será o local do estabelecimento.

Como fazer isso?

OBS: estou desenvolvendo em Wordpress.

Exemplo: http://www.multimercados.com.br/lojas-multi-detalhe/multi-fernandes

Comment: O que vc já fez?

Comment: Eu só tenho a página com o mapa. Mas queria criar esse campo para o usuário colocar o seu endereço e ele traçar a rota até o destino. Porém, não sei como fazer.

Answer (score 0):

Segue um exemplo da pagina da api do google maps:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- This stylesheet contains specific styles for displaying the map
         on this page. Replace it with your own styles as described in the
         documentation:
         https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/maps/documentation/javascript/demos/demos.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var chicago = {lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65};
        var indianapolis = {lat: 39.79, lng: -86.14};

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: chicago,
          scrollwheel: false,
          zoom: 7
        });

        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
          map: map
        });

        // Set destination, origin and travel mode.
        var request = {
          destination: indianapolis,
          origin: chicago,
          travelMode: 'DRIVING'
        };

        // Pass the directions request to the directions service.
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
          if (status == 'OK') {
            // Display the route on the map.
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          }
        });
      }

    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Referência](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/?hl=pt-br)

Comment: Mas e como eu faria para Wordpress?

Comment: Ai vc pode pesquisar um plugin para google maps, exitem vários, por exemplo em uma pesquisa rápida https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-google-map-plugin/ mas nunca usei nenhum. Teste alguns e veja qual atende a sua necessidade.